# how do i forever run a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, slider

I wrote an image slider script in **javascript** but the the problem is the slider function is running only one time . I want to run forever the slider function . I tried to loop the function with this code:

```
function abc(){  //Function for image slider
    //Slider codes here 
}

for(count = 0; count <= 6; count++){  //Forever loop
    count = 0;
    abc();  //Call the slider function
       if(count == 0){
             abc();  //Return call the function
       }
}else{
}
```

**Please tell me what was the prblem in my script ?**

Comment: You can realize endless loop with: `while (true) {..}, for (;;) {..}, function a() { ... a() }`, but try to use timeouts, because such a loop is a massive performance issue

Answer (score 6):

`setInterval` method.

From MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function. Returns an intervalID.

Comment: This is the right answer. No need for a for loop. Just reference your abc function in a setInterval call.

Comment: I don't understand . please discus in a few words .

Answer (score 1):

For running a piece of code forever

```
while (true){
    // code here to run forever
}
```

For running a function forever

```
function doForever(){
    // code of function
}
while (true){
    doForever();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `setInterval` function:

```
setInterval(function myFunction(){
  //my function
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

1st method:

```js
while (true) {
    // code
}
```

2nd method:

```js
function forever() {
    // code
    forever()
}
forever()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a basic concept, "Recursion".

Calling a function by it-self.

```
function abc(){  //Function for image slider
    //Slider codes here
     abc();
}
```

You can use if conditions and exit from it when ever you want.

Just declare a

```
var i = 0; 
if (i < 10) {
 // Loop
 } else {
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This will cause a stack overflow.

Comment: "how do i *forever* run a function in javascript?" He doesn't want to exit.

Comment: I don't understand . please discus in a few words .

Comment: You can't do recursion forever.